# Do the infusions granted by the Kinetic Knight archetype replace the ones you normally choose at this level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype, kineticist

The title say it all, I had to look on d20pfsrd for the [Kinetic Knight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/archetypes/paizo-llc-kineticist-archetypes/kinetic-knight-kineticist-archetype/) archetype since I couldn't find it in my own language and I am not sure about the wording : are the infusions you gain with the archetype "free" (I still choose other infusions to add), or not ?

I am not an experienced player so I cannot tell from a "balance" point of view.

Comment: Welcome! I see you already took to the [tour] so be sure to check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### These are "free" infusions

Note that the wording on [Elemental Blade](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/archetypes/paizo-llc-kineticist-archetypes/kinetic-knight-kineticist-archetype/#Elemental_Blade_Su) does not state that the Infusions are replaced. You simply gain these extra infusions. The Infusion ability is merely changed, and you are replacing other abilities to gain them:

> This ability alters kinetic blast and infusions, and replaces metakinesis and metakinetic master.

For further evidence that the infusions are not replaced by Elemental Blade, look at [Knight’s Resolve](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/archetypes/paizo-llc-kineticist-archetypes/kinetic-knight-kineticist-archetype/#Knights_Resolve_Ex):

> This ability replaces the kineticist infusion gained at 3rd level and supercharge.

You can see that by taking this archetype you are only losing the 3rd level infusion. If Elemental Blade would already replace all the other infusions, this line from Knight's Resolve would make no sense.